# how to pass -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled flag While installing bitnami/keycloak helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

Given below is my command to install bitnami keycloak on my kubernetes cluster

```
helm install kc --set auth.adminPassword=admin,auth.adminUser=admin,service.httpPort=8180 bitnami/keycloak -n my-namespace
```

I want to import realms(contains users,groups,clients and roles) into my keycloak but before i do that i need to enable upload scripts flag , most of you might already know that we can do that in using standalone.sh as given below
on standalone keycloak installation

```
bin/standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10 -Dkeycloak.profile.featur
e.upload_scripts=enabled
```

can someone help me how can I do this using helm install command by passing flags just as I am doing for `auth.adminPassword=admin,auth.adminUser=admin,service.httpPort=8180`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In your Keycloak yaml file you need to add the field `extraEnvVars` and set the `KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS` environment variable as shown in the example below:

```
keycloak:
  enabled: true
  auth:
    adminUser: admin
    adminPassword: secret
  extraEnvVars:
    - name: KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS
      value: -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled    
  extraVolumeMounts:
   ...
```

Bear in mind, however, that the feature `upload_scripts` will be remove from Keycloak in the future.

From [Keycloak Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#using-keycloak-administration-console-to-upload-scripts):

> Ability to upload scripts through the admin console is deprecated and
> will be removed in a future version of Keycloak

Comment: What could be the reason, that this does nothing? I mean I am trying to activate a preview feature like you doing. But it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

As dreamcrash said, the `upload_scripts` feature is deprecated. As to what is the replacement, the Keycloak documentation says:

> Administrators should always deploy scripts directly to the server using a JAR file to prevent attacks when you run scripts at runtime.

Meaning that you should upload your scripts as a JAR file into a specific folder (`/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/` in case of a docker container?), and avoid putting them into the real import file. More info in the Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#deploy-the-script-jar).